# Overriding default timestamp names aren't working in Lumen 7

Tags: laravel, database-migration, lumen

I have done this in model...

```
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
```

And it doesn't work.

In migration file I have done...

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
 *
 * @param  int  $precision
 * @return void
 */
public function timestamps($precision = 0)
{
    $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();

    $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
}
```

This is the `timestamps` method inside `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` method. Overriding `CREATED_AT` or `UPDATED_AT` has nothing to do with that. It will create `created_at` and `updated_at` column in your table.

You may use `timestamp` such as `$table->timestamp(MYMODEL:: CREATED_AT);`

```
/**
 * Create a new timestamp column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  int  $precision
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition
 */
public function timestamp($column, $precision = 0)
{
    return $this->addColumn('timestamp', $column, compact('precision'));
}
```